# Treat datum using format function

Tags: r

If only the last line is out of the width range, like the sample, I want to add a space at just that line.

I tried to do this.

```
a <- c(1 : 8)
b <- rep(43, 8)
c <- c(16, 19, 20, 22, 28, 28, 28, 28)
d <- c(-2814, -1474, -1012, -2, -1.6739, -0.012139, -0.31399, -2.5296E-06)
e <- c("Others 2107", "Others 2110", "Others 2111", "Others 2113", "Others 2119", "Others 2119", "Others 2119", "Others 2119")

a1 <- format(a, width = 10, justify = "right")
b1 <- format(cbind(b, c), width = 9, justify = "right")
c1 <- format(d, width = 10, justify = "right")
d1 <- format(e, justify = "left")

lines <- cbind(a1, b1, c1, d1)
lines <- apply(lines, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")

print(lines)

         1        43        16       -2814 Others 2107
         2        43        19       -1474 Others 2110
         3        43        20       -1012 Others 2111
         4        43        22          -2 Others 2113
         5        43        28     -1.6739 Others 2119
         6        43        28   -0.012139 Others 2119
         7        43        28    -0.31399 Others 2119
         8        43        28 -2.5296E-06 Others 2119
```

I want to have this result.

```
         1        43        16      -2814 Others 2107
         2        43        19      -1474 Others 2110
         3        43        20      -1012 Others 2111
         4        43        22         -2 Others 2113
         5        43        28    -1.6739 Others 2119
         6        43        28  -0.012139 Others 2119
         7        43        28   -0.31399 Others 2119
         8        43        28 -2.5296E-06 Others 2119
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `formatC` for `d`, and better `Map` then.

```
> a1 <- format(a, width=10, justify="right")
> b1 <- format(b, width=9, justify="right")
> c1 <- format(c, width=9, justify="right")
> d1 <- formatC(as.character(d), width=10)
> e1 <- format(e, justify="left")
> Map(\(...) paste(..., collapse=''), a1, b1, c1, d1, e1) |> unlist() |> unname()
[1] "         1        43        16       -2814 Others 2107"
[2] "         2        43        19       -1474 Others 2110"
[3] "         3        43        20       -1012 Others 2111"
[4] "         4        43        22          -2 Others 2113"
[5] "         5        43        28     -1.6739 Others 2119"
[6] "         6        43        28   -0.012139 Others 2119"
[7] "         7        43        28    -0.31399 Others 2119"
[8] "         8        43        28 -2.5296e-06 Others 2119"
```

If you depend on the capital "E", read in `d` as character (or at least elements with "E", will coerce to character automatically).

```
d <- c(-2814, -1474, -1012, -2, -1.6739, -0.012139, -0.31399, '-2.5296E-06')
```